# Thunderbird msi installer package

Tags: active-directory, msi, thunderbird

I am in need of a thunderbird msi (Microsoft Installer) package which can be deployed via group policies using Microsoft ActiveDirectory.

I am very pleased with the Firefox packaged provided by FrontMotion but unfortunately they do not have packages for Thunderbird. *sob* *sob*

I guess, I could try to do the packaging myself, or do all of the installations by hand :(

I did some searches and found very outdated packages by ZettaServe, but no current releases, yet.. Anyone using .msi packaged Thunderbird installations? If you have msi packages, where did you get them from?

regards,
Comradin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a .msi for Thunderbird, but rather than installing by hand, you could roll out [WPKG](http://wpkg.org/) via AD, then use it to roll out [Thunderbird](http://wpkg.org/Thunderbird).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards this project, I did not know this. Ill have a look at it this afternoon, but it sounds very promising.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to create Thunderbird.msi and Firefox.msi with WiX:
http://www.klaus-hartnegg.de/gpo/msi_firefox_wix.html
http://www.klaus-hartnegg.de/gpo/msi_thunderbird.html

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla is now providing a Windows MSI 64-bit Package:

- https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/

To retrieve the latest Thunderbird release use the following url. See [README.txt](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/latest/README.txt) for other languages.

- https://download.mozilla.org/?product=thunderbird-msi-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=en-US